# Upgrade lock from mongo 2.4 to 2.6 wont go away

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have upgrade 3 months ago a mongoDB sharded cluster from 2.4.9 to 2.6.1 . I haven't faced any issues with the upgrade and my cluster working fine, but i still see the initial lock that required to update metadata to v5 on my config servers.

```
     "_id" : "configUpgrade",
    "process" : "pgdb2:27017:1399361525:1804289383",
    "state" : 0,
    "ts" : ObjectId("53688ff569fb6f34e9a2d398"),
    "when" : ISODate("2014-05-06T07:32:05.343Z"),
    "who" : "pgdb2:27017:1399361525:1804289383:mongosMain:846930886",
    "why" : "upgrading config database to new format v5"
```

Does anybody knows if this is bug or if it is going to affect any future operation?

Comment: Have you followed http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/ by the letters?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Yes,  the weird is that temp mongos i used for upgrade meta-data seems to release the lock     2014-05-06T10:32:05.702+0300 [mongosMain] distributed lock 'configUpgrade/pgdb2:27017:1399361525:1804289383' unlocked.

Comment: The upgrade lock record is not removed post upgrade. The "state" of 0 means the lock is not being held. You can ignore or remove manually.

Comment: Thanks @JamesWahlin , is there any document that describes lock states?

Comment: I have not found documentation but there is a comment in the 2.6 code detailing: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/s/type_locks.h#L243

Comment: Thanks, 0: Unlocked | 1: Locks in contention | 2: Lock held

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade lock record is not removed post upgrade. A "state" of 0 means the lock is not being held. You can ignore or remove manually.

The lock definitions for MongoDB 2.6 are [available here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/s/type_locks.h#L243) and are:

> 0: Unlocked | 1: Locks in contention | 2: Lock held